# acronym package and small caps only for some words

Tags: acronyms, small-caps

I'm using `acronym` package to define acronyms and abbreviations in my thesis.
I like to write acronyms in small caps, but I need to write some abbreviations in lower case.

Reading tha package documentation, I could find:

```
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{\acsfont{#1}}}}
```

Changing `\textbf` to `\textsc` I can to change all the acronyms in small caps, but I can't do it only for some of them.

E.g.:

```
\begin{acronym}[CGUE]
\acro{cgue}[cgue]{Corte di giustizia dell'Unione europea}
\acro{cgue}[cedu]{Corte europea dei diritti dell'uomo}
\acro{c.p.}{Codice penale}
\acro{d.lgs.}{Decreto legislativo}
\end{acronym}
```

I need to have CGUE and CEDU in small caps, and c.p. and d.lgs. in lower case.

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `\acro{cgue}[\textsc{cgue}]{...}`. However, IIRC neither computer modern nor latin modern has a bold sans serif small caps variant. This is why I use `libertine` in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}% we need a font with bold small caps
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{acronym}

\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{\acsfont{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}[CGUE]
  \acro{cgue}[\textsc{cgue}]{Corte di giustizia dell'Unione europea}
  \acro{cedu}[\textsc{cedu}]{Corte europea dei diritti dell'uomo}
  \acro{c.p.}{Codice penale}
  \acro{d.lgs.}{Decreto legislativo}
\end{acronym}

\ac{cgue}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, you are right. I tried in advance your solution in my thesis file and I get the error: "Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line ..." and I thought it was a general problem. Your solution is working in another file, so I need to solve this error, but maybe it's another topic.